# php Form calculater how can i fix this

Tags: php, calculator

OK i am making a form that calculates line 1+ line 2 +*.01% then adds line 3+ line 4 then gives a total. I am having a problem with *.01 it works with just the first two but when i add the last two it drops one line if i take it out all four add fine.

```
<?php
if (count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST["calc15TextArea2"])){
    // add First and Second Numbers
    $sum = $_POST["indexEditbox1"] + $_POST["indexEditbox2"]*.01+ $_POST      ["calc15Editbox3"] + $_POST ["calc15Editbox4"];
    // their sum is diplayed as
    echo "Total is $ $sum";
}
?>
```

Comment: JavaScript is notoriously bad at floating point math. You are better off scaling to an integer then dividing when you are done

Comment: @Orangepill this is php

Comment: @Orangepill You actually made me chuckle a bit

Comment: Not relevant but still true :)

Answer (score 0):

wrap all your post vars in `intval()` like eg `intval($_POST['indexEditBox2'])`

this function will get the integer value out of the string. (use the equivalent functions such as `floatval()` if they are not integers)

**edit:** Also try `0.01` in stead of `.01`. Given that this just is a wild hunch, I just might be that the `.`. is picked up as the concatenation operator.

so try:

```
    $sum = floatval( $_POST["indexEditbox1"] ) + floatval( $_POST["indexEditbox2"] ) * 0.01+ floatval( $_POST["calc15Editbox3"] ) + floatval( $_POST["calc15Editbox4"] ) ;
```

**edit2:** See the comments! multiplications and divisions take precedence over adding and subtracting.

Comment: Here is a link to the test page so you can see what it is doing. I don't under stand why when i add *.01 I get 1= and if i remove *.01 all four work?????

Comment: link to test page http://derolds.com/calc15.php i checked and it just adds weird. when i add this to the code *.01 i get 302 not 402  100+100 x 1% +100+100=402 i used x and % as math example

Comment: @DeroldFellmeth Just is just a guess. But did you also try `0.01` in stead of just `.01`? I'm really not sure, but the `.` might also be picked up as the concatenation operator.

Comment: @DeroldFellmeth  100+100*0.01+100+100=301 !!! omg. Is this a wild goose chase ? When calculating, multiplication and divisions. always take precedence over adding/subtracting. (And powers/roots take precedence over multiplications and divisions.) ... So automatically you have to deal with 100+(100*0.01)+100+100 which is 301. That is calculus 101, given on elementary schools.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html 5 you can get around using `floatval` and `intval` by specify the input type on your form inputs in your html markup.

An example would be;

```
<input type="number" name="indexEditBox1" />
```

Then in your php code you could simply do;

```
$sum = $_POST["indexEditbox1"] + $_POST["indexEditbox2"] * .01 + $_POST["calc15Editbox3"] + $_POST ["calc15Editbox4"];
```

Also I would recommend that you wrap your calculations in parenthesis to get the desired outcome, it also makes it easier to read especially as your calculations get more complex. I would no change it to;

```
$sum = (($_POST["indexEditbox1"] + $_POST["indexEditbox2"]) * .01) 
       + ($_POST["calc15Editbox3"] + $_POST ["calc15Editbox4"]);
```

If you are not using html5 or feel the need to be secure as people can inject data into forms you should use the `intval` or `floatval` functions.

Comment: even with html5, i would still do the intval/floatval functions to sanitize any user input, because an attacker could easily still send a string where you would expect a number.

Comment: OK the first code still drops a calc15editbox only adds 3 boxes.The second only adds indexeditbox1 and 2 and *.01

Comment: The second code block, executes: ((index1 + index2) * 0.01) + (calc15box3 + calc15box4). If you wanted to add the total of 0.01 to the overall total of index1 and 2, you would do: ((index1 + index2) * 0.01) + (index1 + index2 + calc15box3 + calc15box4).

Comment: OK i added parenthesis and changed .01 to 1.01 and i had to change one of the parenthesis. Link to first test page [derolds.com/calc15.php][1] second test page [derolds.com/calc18.php][2] Well it works. Hope this will help some one if they are trying to make the same type of form calculator. Thank You for all the help!! ----------------------<?php if (count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST["calc15TextArea2"])){ $sum = (floatval($_POST["indexEditbox1"]) + floatval($_POST["indexEditbox2"])) * 1.01+ floatval($_POST["calc15Editbox3"]) + floatval($_POST["calc15Editbox4"]); echo "Total is $ $sum"; } ?>

Comment: @DeroldFellmeth If it helped you consider accepting it as the answer to help others also, good luck!